# Spring - Unit Test with Mock - How to mock a Custom Collector in a Service unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, domain-driven-design

I have an annoying problem.

I have a service(used in a RestController) which fetches data from Repository and doing some transformation to fetched data. I use a custom collector in my transformation. So it looks like:

```
@RestController
class myController() {
    Service myService

    @GetMapping()
    void getResults{
       Collection col = myService.fetch();
       // some file download logic
    }

}

@Service
class myService() {
Repository repository
Collector myCollector

    Collection fetch() {
    return repository
        .getSomeResults()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(someKey, myCollector)
        .values();
    }

}
```

Here, when I want to unit test the service method fetch(), I can mock repository but if I want to mock custom collector, I need to stub all 5 methods. Except finishing(), others are quite meaningless to mock.

I don't want to decrease test coverage.
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Why do you have to mock your collector? It's not injected?

Comment: On unit test of fetch() in MySeviceTest.java, shouldn't I only use "real" MyService, and don't make real calls to injected beans? Otherwise, I would be testing different dependencies in a single test class.

Comment: Your custom collector is an injected bean? Why?

Comment: Yes, annotated by @component

Comment: what will happen if real method is called on custom collector? it will just collect the data that returned from mocked repository. what is your question exactly? do you have any problem?

Comment: So you are saying I shouldn't make my collector a bean, just instantiate it?

Comment: I'm telling you don't need to mock custom collector, just mock repository and remaining flow should go smooth @Melih

Comment: You don't have to really mock it. In case you are using an out of the box implementation like Collectors.summingInt(), would you mock it because you are not testing just your method? Then why mock your custom collector?

Comment: @Deadpool, Therefore, I need to use a real collector object in my fetchTest() ? Do I understand correctly?
I have been always tolled don't make calls to other dependencies in your unit tests, just mock them. As I behave my collector as a bean, I didn't want to use real calls on it. If I don't inject it and use like a simple object, I can instantiate it?

Comment: @Prasanna, in finishing() method, I have a very long logic which actually needs to be tested itself. So that, when I make real calls to my collector, I will be also testing this logic in service class.

Comment: Don't inject it... It should me a static method like Java's Collectors.toSet(), Collectors.toList()

Comment: The idea behind unit testing is that you atomically test your methods. But that does not mean you will have to mock every other method call inside. Say, you have a db call / network call, it makes sense to mock it. But in this case, it's anologous to mocking a Collectors.toList(). There is no harm in not mocking it here. This should not affect your coverage in any ways as long as your Collector has it's own unit tests.

Comment: @Prasanna, okay I will make real calls as this will not be a dependency anymore.

Actually, I was using this collector in a factory method(not injected, directly instantiated) which was a component obviously, but then I moved my factory logic directly to finisher. Instead of throwing away factory, I implemented the collector in this factory, called it 'CustomCollector' instead of Factory and I did not remove Component annotation on top of it. So this problem arised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind unit testing is that you atomically test your methods. But that does not mean you will have to mock every other method call inside.

Say, you have a database call/network call, it makes sense to mock it. It makes sense to mock when the response of your called method decides the branch that will be executed on your called method. But in this case, it's analogous to mocking a `Collectors.toList()`. There is no harm in not mocking it here.

Also, this should not affect your coverage in anyways as long as your custom Collector has its own unit tests